# Replacing negative values with "0" for multiple raster layers using R

Tags: r

i have a set of raster layers in which there are negative values. I want to replace those values with "0". i have tried a code which is working well but the problem is I have to repeat the codes for different years and keep changing the folders every time I change the year. Can a loop be used or something else which will lessen my work?
The following code am using:

```
library(sp)  
library(raster)  
library(rgdal)  

 
setwd('E:/')  
shape<- readOGR('E:/Lipsa(MTech)/Final year project/dataset/study area data/india shapefile wid dist/India_Boundary/India_Boundary.shp')  
plot(shape)  


list1<- list.files(path='E:/Lipsa(MTech)/Final year project/dataset/VHI_VCI_TC__NOAAstar_globe_monthly/TCI/2007',pattern = '.tif$', full.names = T)  
stack_2007<- stack(list1)  
plotRGB(stack_2007, 3,2,1, stretch='lin')  


crs(shape)  
crs(stack_2007[[1]])  
plot(shape, add=T, col='red')  


crp_2007 <- raster::crop(stack_2007,shape)  
plotRGB(crp_2007, 3,2,1, stretch='lin')  
msk_2007<-raster::mask(crp_2007,shape)  
plotRGB(msk_2007, 3,2,1, stretch='lin')  


fun = function(x){x[x < 0] = 0;     
return(x)}  
a=calc(msk_2007,fun)  
plotRGB(a, 3,2,1, stretch='lin')  


setwd('E:/Lipsa_data/TCI_india_nd_rmvd/2007')  
uns_2007<-unstack(a)  
TCI_2007<- paste(seq_along(uns_2007), ".tif",sep="")  
for(i in seq_along(uns_2007)){writeRaster(uns_2007[[i]], bylayer=TRUE, file=TCI_2007[i])}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do any of the steps in R, such as reading in your raster data? Its hard to know from your question where we need to start, or if you should first read a general R or R-spatial tutorial. I don't think this question is "off-topic" but it does need to be made a bit clearer.

Comment: i have edited my question a bit

Comment: And has the question changed? Your function `fun` in there seems to answer the question in the title about replacing negatives with zero. If you need to loop over years then yes you can loop over years, construct paths using `file.path` or `paste`, and so on. Wrap things up in functions if they get too complex.